# Pgsql connection using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have to develop a program  using c# .NET framwork 4.5, and i'm using odbc to connect to pgsql database.

The problem is when I downgrade the .NET framework to 4.0 the program  shows the message

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified

in the connection method.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npgsql release after 3.0.8 works with .Net Framework 4.5. Please downgrade your Npgsql driver if your are using version > 3.0.8

Click [here to download required verison of Npgsql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)